# How can I calculate a power of 1..n on Haskell?

Tags: loops, math, haskell

How can I calculate a power (^2) of 1..n on Haskell? "n" is input number. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: What does it mean to calculate the power of a list of numbers?  Do you mean the product?  What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  Just posting a problem without an attempted solution isn't encouraged.

Comment: I have attempted to write the program but I know Haskell too bad.

Comment: Easy: `main = print . map (^2) . enumFromTo 1 . read =<< getLine`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
main = do
  nStr <- getLine
  let n = read nStr
  print . take n $ map (^2) [1..]
```

Stack overflow is inappropriate for questions that have not been well-researched.  Hit [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/), the [Haskell wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell), or a combination of the two before you post here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
take 5 $ map (^2) [1..]
```

which gives:

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Obviously you can swap 2 with any other power there.

```
take 5 $ map (^3) [1..]
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125]
```

Comment: Two-Bit Alchemist, thank you for the help! But I get `Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'` error with the provided code.

Comment: If you're doing `IO` in Haskell it's a whole different ballpark I'm afraid. IO is a whole separate part of the language because it doesn't fit well with the whole functional, no side-effects paradigm. Checkout [Chapter 9 of Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output).